# OpenXML C#: Change color of a word in wordprocessing

Tags: c#, openxml, wordprocessingml

I want to change the color of a word. I am adding color in runproperties but instead of changing color of single word it change the color of whole line. see the code.

```
void AppendStyle(string document, string word, string col)
    {
        try
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
                    WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true)) //Open file from path
            {
                var body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                var paras = body.Elements<Paragraph>();
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Color color = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Color();

                foreach (var para in paras)
                {
                    foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
                    {
                        foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
                        {
                            if (text.Text.Contains(word))
                            {

                                color.Val = col;
                                run.AppendChild(color);
                                return;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                wordDoc.Close(); // close the template file

            }
```

Comment: how did you save the document ? after you created the word with new color

Answer (score 0):

What Word does under the covers when you color only a part of a sentence is that it splits the sentence into multiple runs. You need to do the same thing.

Comment: the word is like **<SERVICE_NAME>** and when it found the word it starts coloring the whole sentence after that word. what should i do to stop coloring the whole sentence. please help

Comment: Is there any other way to color a word ?

Comment: @HamzaZaidi, like I said - you need to split the sentence into multiple runs.